# wso2 stream processor: flow architecture

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am looking into wso2 cep and I try to understand the right architecture for sensor data.

In my case we receive well formed data. The entity looks like this:

```
private UUID sensorId;
private Double value;
private Long timeInNanoSeconds;
```

This data needs to be processed, there are alarms that can be set on sensors / values. There are custom calculations, where the value of sensorId X is added to sensorId Y.

Is the approach correct to create a sensorStream and send all sensor data from all devices / sensors to this flow?